# How to mask or crop an image region after applying connected components

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have an RGB image (NxMx3 ndarray) having various regions. After applying clustering and connected components (**skimage** [measure.label](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) ), I got an NxM ndarray with labeled regions.

How can I use these labeled areas for cropping or masking pixels from the original image (NxMx3)? In the end I want to take only the background (with label=0) and to extract some average color out of it.

Comment: See the section on [boolean masks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html). Essentially, numpy lets you index your image array with the label array and recover only the entries where the mask is `True`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It turned out, boolean masks are effective, and easy to create as well, since numpy.ones() or numpy.zeros() with dtype=np.bool gives a boolean matrix with the shape of the image(NxM). Then applying it on an RGB image ( NxMx3 ) allows a particular collor (RGB vector) to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `image` is your source image `labels` is your label image, you can grab the pixels corresponding to label `j` with:

```
pixels_j = image[labels == j]
```

This will give you an `(Nj, 3)` array of those pixels. You can then recover the mean color with:

```
mean_color = np.mean(pixels_j, axis=0)
```

If you are going to do this for many images, though, you should probably use `skimage.measure.regionprops`.

Comment: Thanks Juan! That was really helpful.